# How to acquire security advisory for CentOS?

Tags: centos, vulnerability-management

I've been seeing security advisory number like CESA-2017:1842, and after search I could only find some of them in mailing list archives such as [this](https://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-cr-announce/2017-August/004249.html).

Is there a website like https://usn.ubuntu.com or https://access.redhat.com/security/ that dedicated to the announcement of CentOS related vulnerabilities?

Comment: You might find this useful: [Recent CentOS security alerts](https://lwn.net/Alerts/CentOS/). This is not an authoritative link, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, whatever applies to RHEL should apply to respective CentOS release. Read more here on the similarity part (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27323/is-centos-exactly-the-same-as-rhel). [1]

Also best way to search for CVE is to go to https://cve.mitre.org/ and search for CVE List with keyword like "CentOS". e.g. (https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=CentOS)

Edit: In the provided first link, an answer mentions "CVEs (Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures) are not tested on CentOS, and it is expensive to test them properly." I didn't got any source to verify this claim.

Comment: actually, it is not, in practice, I found that several software package fix may be only available to RHEL , but not to CentOS,for a undeterminable time.

Comment: @Sajuuk that's interesting to know. This can be crucial factor in choosing CentOS for production systems.